# Smoother gradient bar legend with pdf

Tags: r, ggplot2

When using the [PDF Graphics Device](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/pdf.html) (`png`) there is a difference in the ggplot2 legend in comparison to the `png` version.  The gradient is smoother in the `png` whereas distinct gradients stripes are visible in the `pdf`.  I have looked at the documentation for `pdf` and adjusted point size but this doesn't seem to make the gradient smoother.  How can I make the `pdf` gradient smooth like the `png`?

**The PDF**

[image]

**The PNG**

[image]

```
png(file="grad1.png")
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=cyl, y=mpg, fill=hp)) +
    geom_point() +
    scale_fill_gradient(low="grey88", high="black")
dev.off()
```

**# Versus**

```
pdf(file="grad1.pdf")
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=cyl, y=mpg, fill=hp)) +
    geom_point() +
    scale_fill_gradient(low="grey88", high="black")
dev.off()
```

Comment: that's odd, but have you tried to play with nbin in `guide_colourbar()`?

Comment: actually, I see discrete levels in the png as well on my machine. Could it be your image viewer that's doing some interpolation on the png file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can increase `nbin` in `guide_colourbar()`,

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=cyl, y=mpg, fill=hp)) +
    geom_point() +
    scale_fill_gradient(low="grey88", high="black")

last_plot() + guides(fill = guide_colourbar(nbin=4, raster=FALSE))

last_plot() + guides(fill = guide_colourbar(nbin=300, raster=FALSE))
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it happen when you use the Cairo library?

```
library('Cairo')
CairoPDF('output.pdf')
    #plot
dev.off()
```

Comment: Sorry but this is no better.

Answer (score 0):

In looking at `?scale_fill_gradient`, it says to see "`seq_gradient_pal` for details on underlying palette". In looking at the source of `seq_gradient_pal` from the `scales` package, it's interesting to see that the function makes a gradient from several discrete colors. `seq_gradient_pal` is used in the `scale_fill_gradient` function ([source](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/R/scale-gradient.r)). I can't figure out if this means that a gradient is then always estimated with `seq_gradient_pal` or if a gradient fill is later made in the vector image. If the gradient is indeed estimated from several discrete colors, then this might be the reason for your problem.

See also the comment about gradients in this [article](http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2011-1/RJournal_2011-1_Murrell.pdf) by Paul Murrell. An excerpt: "An example is gradient fills, which are not explicitly supported by the R graphics engine". However, the `gridSVG` package does now support gradient fills.

Following up on @baptiste's comment. Note that `guide_colourbar` has a `raster` option that is, by default, set to `TRUE`. Looking at `?guide_colourbar`, you can see that "`If TRUE then the colorbar is rendered as a raster object. If FALSE then the colorbar is rendered as a set of rectangles. Note that not all graphics devices are capable of rendering raster image.`"